# C - Is "acos()" differ for each math.h header file?

Tags: c, math, distance, trigonometry

Im working on one of a PIC24F series microcontroller to calculate distance between two latitude and longitude cordinates. I've included "math.h" header file for PIC24F in the code. The problem is acos(1) gives "0.000345" value, but im expecting "0.000086". The same code i've worked in eclipse by using eclipse's math.h header file, it give correct value "0.000086". What is the problem? Is "acos()" differ for each math.h header file?

```
.....
theta = lon1 - lon2;
printf("%f",theta);
dist = sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * cos(deg2rad(theta));
printf("%f", dist);
dist = acos(dist);
printf("%f", dist);
dist = rad2deg(dist);
printf("%f", dist);
.....
```

After passing the coordinates, the each "dist" variable value is below

Eclipse Output:

```
 0.006082
 1.000000
 0.000086
 0.004939
```

Microcontroller Output:

```
0.006088 
1.000000
0.000345
0.019782
```

Thanks

Comment: Just asking, are you really using nested functions?

Comment: Huh ? `acos(1)` should be 0.0, no? Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rather than just the code you happen to be working on.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Hi, im using three seperate functions inside a main function.

Comment: @user25770: [acos(1) == 0](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=acos%281%29). Not 0.000345, and not 0.000086. I smell a code problem here.

Comment: Why did you delete the code?

Comment: @weston Here i posted the code. Pls check it.

Comment: Have you tried `printf("%f", acos(1f));`? and print these to a higher number of places: `printf("%.20f", dist);` As per potatoswatter's answer, you probably will see it is not exactly `1f`

Comment: Hi @weston. How i pass "1f" in acos function? It gives an error.

Comment: Sorry `printf("%f", acos(1.0f));` or just `printf("%f", acos(1));`

Comment: @weston Perhaps you mean `printf("%f", acosf(1));`

Comment: @Potatoswatter I've tried to print the exact floating point of 'dist = sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * cos(deg2rad(theta));
printf("%.10f", dist);'  I used **"%.10f"**. Im getting in eclipse's "0.9999999963" and in PIC "0.9999999404".

Comment: @user25770: Ah... you meant `acos`, as on `man 1 acos`... not `acos( 1 )` as in `acos( 1.0 )`. In that case, the existing answers are spot-on. [Floating point maths is never precise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004); and between different implementations running on different hardware, accrued rounding errors etc. your numbers will slowly diverge when you put them through consecutive function calls like you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that trigonometry is ***hard***. Precise algorithms are either very slow or very large, fast algorithms are either very large or very imprecise, and small algorithms are either very slow or very imprecise. Large systems can get away with large implementations, but embedded systems, with their smaller resources and lower speed, usually have to make do with less precise results.

Comment: Doesn't the standard actually define the maximum allowed margin of error for these functions? Aside from `acos(1)` being neither `0.000086` nor `0.000345`, the difference between those two is too large to be explained by less-precise implementation.

Comment: I've seen implementations of perfectly reasonable functions go pear-shaped near boundary conditions.

Comment: `acos` should be accurate to 1 ULP on any desktop computer platform.

Comment: PICs are not any kind of desktop platform.

Comment: Some might say that they are not a very good controller platform either.

Comment: Eclipse only runs on desktop platforms. (Or *should* only be run, anyway; it's heavyweight.)

Answer (score 6):

The GNU library, and any other that attempts conformance to floating-point standards, will return zero for `acos(1)`. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/936cdba6dc29f182).

Most likely, the argument is not exactly 1 but slightly smaller. `acos(1 - FLT_EPSILON/2)`, passing the last single-precision number before 1, yields `0.00034526` which is your result. Perhaps the PIC, being a very low-power device, does not implement double precision math. No smaller (but nonzero) `acos` result is possible in single-precision arithmetic.

Besides that, the rounding of floating-point results, which is the source of calculation errors, may vary between platforms.

Comment: FLT_EPSILON is the distance from 1 to the NEXT double which is TWICE as big as the the distance to the previous, because 1 is the point of an exponent jump!!! For that reason what you mean is `acos(1 - 0.5 * FLT_EPSILON)` which is 0.0000000149012. 0.5 is the inverse radix.

Comment: @Coolwater I think that's the `DBL_EPSILON` result, but good catch! Now things line up nicely.

Comment: PIC24 is at the higher end of the PIC family and according to [Microchip](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2680&dDocName=en552209) it does support double precision. Probably some options need to be enable to link the large floating-point library http://www.microchip.com/forums/m633037.aspx